# How to turn off Serilog?

Tags: c#, serilog

We are using Serilog to log items into a db with a Windows service, and the users wanted to be able to do a manual run, so we made a button (on a web page) to make a call to the same code (as a module, not the service itself).

When we added in the code to initialize the log so the code will continue adding to the db log table, it also logs all the http traffic after that as well.  So after this code runs we want to 'turn off' the Logger running on the Webserver.  Is there an easy way to do that?

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString,
                "LOGS")
       .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Do you mean "turn off entirely" or just for the manual action?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt  turn off entirely, we turn it on for the manual run and want to turn it off after.  The service itself has it's own logger running.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Log levels can be modified at runtime with `LoggingLevelSwitch`:

```
var ls = new LoggingLevelSwitch();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(ls)
   .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(...)
   .CreateLogger();
```

Logging will initially be at the `Information` level, you can change this via the switch.

Serilog doesn't define an `Off` level, but you can approximate it with:

```
ls.MinimumLevel = ((LogEventLevel) 1 + (int) LogEventLevel.Fatal);
```

...to turn logging off.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I recognize that the LoggingLevelSwitch can be used as a parameter to set the logging level. But it seems that in order to change the logging level, one would have to redeploy the application in order to change the LoggingLevelSwitch. Is there a way to change the logging level without requiring a new build and deployment? Perhaps via a configuration file or appSettings file?

Answer (score 14):

according to Microsoft documentation for logging if you set the log level to None, all logs will be suppressed.

> To suppress all logs, specify LogLevel.None. LogLevel.None has a value of 6, which is higher than LogLevel.Critical (5).

> Any logs below the minimum level are not:
> Passed to the provider. Logged or displayed.

you can refer to this documentation under Configure logging section. [logging for asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-logging)

for Serilog you can set

```
"Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "6"
}}
```

this configuration will turn off **Serilog**, I try it at run time and it worked.

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work with Serilog? =)

Comment: @GuruStron thank you for your comment, I have been rush in posting the answer.

Comment: I try it and it worked

Comment: FWIW: Basically any numeric value > 6 will disable the sink.

Comment: 100 % worked for me , refer that this need to be added in appsettings.(envirnment).json and number could be replaced by value like in 6 case could be replaced by "None" ,thanks.

Answer (score 13):

This question is a couple of years old, but I happen to be facing a similar problem right now.

The easiest way to turn Serilog's logging off is by creating a new logger **without any sinks**. From Serilog's documentation, [Configuration Basics](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#creating-a-logger):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().CreateLogger();
Log.Information("No one listens to me!");
```

### Edit (08/05/2017)

The solution above is not correct. After some more research, I've found that this can be done by setting a filter when configuring the logger:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Filter.ByExcluding(_ => !IsLoggingEnabled)
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(...)
    .CreateLogger();
```

, where `IsLoggingEnabled` is just a boolean flag.