# Configuring loglevel of custom ILogger<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to configure the loglevel of a custom `ILogger<T>` through configuration. Is this easily possible? I want to restrict logging for this specific handler without touching any general settings.

In my custom case I'm injecting an `ILogger<DataHandledLoggingHandler>` into my class, and would like to disable it in certain environments. What I assumed should work is to add a key "DataHandledLoggingHandler" to the Logging.LogLevel section of appsettings.json, to e.g. "None". However, I still see Warnings in my log sink. My appsetting.Development.json would look like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "DataHandledLoggingHandler": "None",
    }
 ...
```

I've also attempted the fully qualified name including namespace, but still no luck, logging still takes place.

I do use Serilog with Seq and Console sink right now, but got it hooked up to ILogger through the Serilog.Extensions.Logging package

Comment: Try adding the scopes to e.g. SimpleConsole logger. You can then see what the incoming log source is for your message.
`services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddSimpleConsole(opt => opt.IncludeScopes = true))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no `None` option in Serilog's [`LogEventLevel`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/365adaedffa22e1138d3a180288b2bbe9ec243b5/src/Serilog/Events/LogEventLevel.cs) enum. Try using `Fatal` for testing purposes. Also try specifying fully qualified name for `DataHandledLoggingHandler` (i.e. with full namespace - `SomeThing.Something1....DataHandledLoggingHandler`).

If this works but `Fatal` is not enough then you will need to resort to setting up this via code - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30864356/2501279).

Comment: Thanks! What also worked for me in the end was to use SeriLog.MinimumLevel in my json instead of Logging.LogLevel