# .NET 6: how to prevent system-generated logs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog-sinks-mssqlserver

I am using Serilog with .NET 6.0. I can set the `LogLevel` in `appsettings.json` to allow only certain type of logs.

But I need to write only the log messages explicitly written by my code.

For example: if I have set `LogLevel` to `Information`, and in the controller method I am writing one line to the Log:

```
logger.LogInformation(1, "Test message for Information Level.");
```

when it runs I can see this message in DB, but there are also other messages generated by system. I don't need that system-generated messages in my table.

How can I log the messages only written by application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "Microsoft" logging level > Default logging level
By program.cs (Serilog.AspNetCore)

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Fatal)
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Services.AddSerilog(logger);
```

or appsettings.json

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Fatal"
      }
    }
  }
```

Logging level: Verbose-0, Debug-1, Information-2, Warning-3, Error-4, Fatal-5.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Default` log level for namespaces to higher `LogLevel` like `Error` and set yours to a lower one like `Debug` and then you will see mainly your logs.

There is also a `LogLevel` that doesn't write logs at all that can be used for this case, its `None` in Serilog its usually `6`, see link below.

In that way you can control the `LogLevel` for namespace, its by the prefix for example if your application namespace starts with `MyApp`

You can have in `appsettings.json`:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "MyApp": "Debug",
      "MyApp.Controllers": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "None"
    }
  }
```

Read more:

[How filtering rules are applied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#how-filtering-rules-are-applied)

[Log levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#log-level)

[Turn of logs in Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30864356/14081474)

Comment: I don't know the reason. I tested this change, but did not find it working. It still logs all messages.